# Negation not working in JPA Pattern Validator

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to blacklist a few words and blank. But negation is not working in JPA Pattern Validator regex.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?!(|null|na))$", message = "Invalid/Empty input")
```

EDIT:
Looks like none of the flags working. Is it expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `^(?=(?:|null|na)$)` https://regex101.com/r/inGoJx/1 or match them `^(?:|null|na)$`

Comment: No... i meant ?! (negative lookahead) @Thefourthbird

Comment: Ok, try it with a negative lookahead `^(?!(?:|null|na)$)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird does not work

Comment: it seems there is an annotation parameter for the flags only... but non capturing groups are not working as well

Comment: Which flags are you talking about? I see no flags in your code. And it doesn't look like you ever verified that your pattern works in a different context, so there's no reason to blame JPA.

Comment: @Holger flags (such as ignorecase ?i) can be passed as a parameter flags=Flags.IGNORE_CASE, but it does not support lookaheads. And yes I have tested the regex with String.match, it works.

Comment: I didn't ask whether or how you can pass flags. There are no flags in your question and there is no flag that could make your regex work. And your phrase "but it does not support lookaheads" makes no sense in this context. And you obviously did not test this pattern. The group `(|null|na)` contains an empty string as first alternative, hence, does always match, so its negation will never match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a bit late to the party yet to prevent others to struggle like I did, in my case I wanted to avoid certain suffixes, lets say `-INVALID` and `-UNDESIRED`, the pattern that help me with it was:

```java
@Pattern(
            regexp = "^.+?(?<!-INVALID)(?<!-UNDESIRED)$",
            message = "Invalid suffix [-INVALID, -UNDESIRED]")
```